# Не видны переменные и миксины

Tags: html, scss, mixins

Всем привет!
У меня возникла такая ситуация и меня терзают смутные сомнения, что так должно быть.

**Суть:**
У меня есть файл mixins.scss и файл vars.scss. Соответственно миксины и переменные мне нужно присваивать в определённые строки кода в других .scss файлах.

**Моё понимание того, как это должно работать:**
Я импортирую файл mixins.scss и файл vars.scss в основной файл стилей style.scss. В этот же файл я подключаю редактируемый в данный момент .scss файл. И когда я в этом .scss файле импортирую миксин либо использую переменную, всё должно работать.

**Как оно работает у меня на самом деле:**
Мой редактируемый файл .scss не видит ни миксинов, ни переменных до тех пор, пока я не подключу их лично в него. Если они не подключены - получаю ошибки "Undefined variable
Invalid value property

**Вопрос:**
Неужели оно так и должно быть? Ведь по такой логике вещей если у меня будет 20+ файлов .scss, то это нужно будет в каждый из них отдельно подключать миксины и переменные? Разве не должно всё хранится в основном файле стилей и оттуда уже прыгать в нужные файлы?

Comment: «в каждый из них отдельно подключать миксины и переменные» — для меня это звучит вполне логично, потому что явное лучше неявного. Сразу видеть, что такой-то файл зависит от другого такого-то файла — более удобно при поддержке проекта в будущем

Comment: @andreymal в какой-то мере я согласен. Но смотрю как это работает у других - они подключены только один раз в глобальный файл, а потом без проблем используются в других, где нужно, без лишнего подключения каждому

Comment: А можно пример этих самых «других»?

Comment: Уже разобрался, начало работать. Но теперь возникла другая трудность. Сборка одну переменную (например, цвет) видит, а другую (например, размер для брейкпойнта) - не видит.

Comment: А тут нужен [mcve]

Comment: Я понял. Мне просто нужно было перенести нужные переменные в нужный файл. Так как я пользовался шаблоном, а с моим галпом он не хотел работать так же, как у первоисходника))